# using like in an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to sync data between two databases (on the same server) and to achieve that I'm using a store procedure.

The id from database A is int, the id from database B is char(25) and takes the following form: Item. Example, if A.Id is 42, B.Id is Item42

While doing the query to join both databases the strangest behaviour happens:

```
SELECT A.Id, B.id
FROM A.dbo.table as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B.dbo.table as B on (B.id like 'Item42')
```

works like expected but

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar;    
SET @id = '42';

SELECT A.Id, B.id
FROM A.dbo.table as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B.dbo.table as B on (B.id like 'Item' + @id)
```

returns null on B.Id.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is this query working : SELECT A.Id, B.id
FROM A.dbo.table as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B.dbo.table as B on (B.id like 'Item' + 42) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select a.id, b.id
from A.dbo.table as a
left join B.dbo.table as b
  on b.id = 'Item' + convert(varchar, a.id)
```

Otherwise, you're really doing a cross join, since you're not referencing A in B's join clause.

Comment: Your answer led me to the problem. I was using nvarchar instead of varchar =$ silly me

Answer (score 2):

`NVARCHAR` without length specifier is treated as `NVARCHAR(1)` which cannot accomodate `42` and truncates it to `4`.

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar;    
SET @id = '42';

SELECT  @id

--
4
```

Specify a greater length for `@id`:

```
DECLARE @id NVARCHAR(20)
```

Ultimately, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT  A.Id, B.id
FROM    A.dbo.table as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        B.dbo.table as B
ON      B.id = 'Item' + CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(20))
```

This is better than `LIKE` since equality operator is sargable.

Comment: You're right about the length, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The edit is right. I had to cast it to varchar instead of nvarchar

Comment: @Daniel: please post the relevant records from both tables which should be returned in your opinion.

Comment: as I said your edit was right. The problem was that I was using nvarchar instead or varchar. I marked @John Gibb answer as accepted because it was his answer that led me to the problem. Despite that, I gave you both a vote up for the nice answers

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this?:

```
SELECT A.Id, B.id
FROM A.dbo.table as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B.dbo.table as B 
ON B.id = 'Item' + CAST(A.id AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Why are you using a `LIKE` if you are not using a wildcard `'%'`?, and why are you doing a `JOIN` with a static value for id?

Comment: I was using LIKE because database B Id is a little more complicated than Item<Id>. It involves another variable and in fact I'm doing this: like '%,'+ convert(varchar,B.id). I just give a cleaner example so it would be easy to find the problem =)